# How to use index in a while loop which finds the next occurrence each time

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, indexing

I want to find the index of a letter in one string and then replace the letter in the same index but in another string, both strings are members of the dictionary.

however if there is more than one occurrence of the charStr (the single character) in the string it will only give the index of the first occurrence. How do I make it so that the loop would then give the index of the next occurrence of the character instead of just the first occurrence each time the loop runs?

Sorry if this doesnt make sense, Its a bit complicated to explain lol, thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `index()` method takes a second argument that specifies the position at which you start searching.

```
'abcbd'.index('b') # 1
'abcbd'.index('b', 1) # 1
'abcbd'.index('b', 2) # 3
'abcbd'.index('b', 3) # 3
```

So at each iteration, you can use `pos = x('secWord').index(charStr, pos+1)`. However, if the substring is not in the string, it will raise a ValueError:

```
'abcbd'.index('b', 4) # ValueError: substring not found
```

For example:

```
astr = 'abcdbfrgbzb'
charStr = 'b'
occ = astr.count(charStr)
pos = -1
for _ in range(occ):
    pos = astr.index(charStr, pos+1)
    print pos
# 1, 4, 8, 10
```

In your case:

```
def updateGame (x, charStr) :
    occ = x('secWord').count(charStr)
    pos = -1
    for _ in range(occ):
        pos = x('secWord').index(charStr, pos+1)
        x('curGuess')[pos] = charStr
```

Comment: Ah I see, so I could just make a int variable which starts at 0 and then adds 1 on each loop?

Comment: how would I avoid the value error? Would I need to use a try and except block?

Comment: @RJB see latest edit ... if you check the count before and only have `occ` iterations, you won't get the ValueError.

Comment: Sorry but I have just got round to testing the solution and it doesnt actually work, the information that you gave me was correct but I tried using the code you gave me for my case and it wasnt updating the 'curGuess' string when a character was guessed correctly